# SAPUI5 UploadCollection - Which Template for Items?

Tags: sapui5

I bind the items dynamically in the controller because of using a filter with a binding value, which is not possible in XML-View.

My Code:

```
control.bindItems({
                path: "/Products",
                              filters: new sap.ui.model.Filter(
                                {
                                  path: "Workitem",
                                  operator: FilterOperator.EQ,
                                  value1: workitem
                                }),
                templateShareable: false,
                template: new sap.m.StandardListItem()
        });
```

When I remove templateShareable and template, I get an error.
When I remove only template, I get the same error.

With both values included, the app works. But when I fill the items, UploadCollection is still empty. StandardListItem is not the right template I guess.

But which template do I have to choose?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look at the documentation for [sap.m.UploadCollection](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#/api/sap.m.UploadCollection%23aggregations), under 'Aggregations' you can see that is expects 0 to n items of type [sap.m.UploadCollectionItem](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#/api/sap.m.UploadCollectionItem).